# SSRS select parent parameters based on child

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to implement a SSRS report where I need to select values in my parent dropdowns based on the selected value of the child dropdown. My question would be more clear after the following example.

Assume I have 3 multivalued parameters in my SSRS report, **Continents**, **Countries**, and **Cities**.
On report load, the **Continents** parameter will be populated with all continents, **Countries** parameter will be populated with all countries, and the **Cities** parameter will be populated with all cities. Now if a user directly selects a city, I want to update the **Countries** and **Continents** parameters with the relevant values.
For e.g., if I select New Delhi in the **Cities** parameter, India and Asia should get selected in the **Countries** and **Continents** parameter respectively.

I hope my question is clear. My requirement involves several more dropdowns, but if it works for the above case, I think it would work for me.
Is this possible?

Comment: Is it supposed to filter in only one way or also the other (select continent to get all countries int it etc.)?

Comment: @kyooryu It should work both ways. When you select a parent(Continents), the child dropdowns (Countries,Cities) should get filtered. When a child is selected, the parent dropdown values need to only be selected, not filtered.

Comment: From what I know it is impossible to create two-way relationship between parameters - you can only cascade them in one way.

Comment: Seconding @kyooryu - not possible in SSRS; cascading parameters only flow one direction.  Only way you're going to accomplish this is writing your own front-end for the report and rendering in a a reportviewer control.

Comment: @kyzen yeah that's how I'll be doing it.. Thanks.